# VMware Sysprep with Custom Unattended.xml

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, sysprep, unattended

I was looking into using VCenter for deploying VMs and wanted to take advantage of the built-in template features and the ability to make use of unattended.xml files. I have a Windows 7 template that I would like to use to spin off copies of this VM. I also have an extensive unattended.xml file that we have built over time. I know that you can use the built-in wizard to create an answer file, but I am wanting to import my own unattended.xml file. Is this possible? I hope that my question makes sense.